# How to count the specific values from firebase in android studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

There are four seasons in the category, but I want to count only "Spring". Finally, I want to print the counted number on the screen.
What should I do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpC7v.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uyOJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to get the number of children that exist under the "Products" node, which has the field `productSeasonCategory` set to "Spring". If that's the case, then instead of using a database reference, you should use a query, as you can see in the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference productsRef = db.child("Users").child(uid).child("Products");
Query queryByProductSeasonCategory = productsRef.orderByChild("productSeasonCategory").equalTo("Spring");
queryByProductSeasonCategory.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            long count = task.getResult().getChildrenCount();
            Log.d("TAG", "count: " + count);
            Text1.settext(String.valueOf(count)) //Added
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank alot mr.Alex. If i want to show this count number in axtivity, Text1.settext(count)?

Comment: You're very welcome, kmskms. So did my solution solve your problem?

Comment: If i want to show this count number in activity, Text1.settext(count)?

Comment: In that case, please see my updated answer. Is it ok now?

Comment: Yes, it is okay now

Comment: Good to hear that. So can I help you with other information?

Comment: No, I don't have any more. I'd like to ask you again if I do anything extra later. Thank you so much my teacher.